# Sending an order to oanda

Tags: python, rest, api, jupyter-notebook

I want to send an order to oanda to make a transaction,I use ipython notebook to compile my code,this is my code:

```
import oandapy

trade_expire=datetime.now()+timedelta(days=1)
trade_expire=trade_expire.isoformat("T")+"Z"
oanda=oandapy.API(environment='practice',access_token='XXXX....')
account_id=xxxxxxx

response=oanda.create_order(account_id,instrument='USD_EUR',units=1000,side='buy',/
type='limit',price=1.105,expire=trade_expire)
```

But the error is：

```
OandaError: OANDA API returned error code 4 (The access token provided does
            not allow this request to be made)
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I am facing the same issue right now, any findings?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but when sending orders via curl commands.

The problem has to do with which API you are using from which account.

I notice in your python it says "practice," so you'll want to make sure the API token you generated is from within your practice account. Live accounts and practice accounts each use their own API tokens, and your commands will need to match.

You might also look elsewhere in your python, where it actually pings OandA's server.

For example, when using curl, a live account uses

> "https://**api-fxtrade**.oanda.com/v3/accounts/<ACCOUNT>/orders"

and a practice account uses

> "https://**api-fxpractice**.oanda.com/v3/accounts/<ACCOUNT>/orders"

Using your API token generated on your live account in a practice account will produce the error you're asking about.

Comment: Your post makes a lot of sense, thank you. However, I have not idea where do you generate the token for the practice account specifically.